# react-native-chart-kit not working with navigation react native - expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have statistics component in my app that uses this library :

```
import {
    LineChart,
    BarChart,
    PieChart,
    ProgressChart,
    ContributionGraph,
    StackedBarChart
} from "react-native-chart-kit";
```

this page works correctly when i make it the first page loaded when the app is launched :

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import MainMenu from "../modules/MainMenu/MainMenu-screen";
import Login from "../modules/Login/Login-screen";
import StatistiqueGlobale from "../modules/statGlobale/Statistique-screen"
const LoginStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  StatistiqueGlobale: {
    screen: StatistiqueGlobale,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "StatistiqueGlobale",
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
  },

  MainMenu: {
    screen: MainMenu,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "MainMenu",
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
```

but i need the app to start with the login page and then to navigate to statistics page from the main menu :
so navigation should be like this :

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import MainMenu from "../modules/MainMenu/MainMenu-screen";
import Login from "../modules/Login/Login-screen";
import StatistiqueGlobale from "../modules/statGlobale/Statistique-screen"
const LoginStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  StatistiqueGlobale: {
    screen: StatistiqueGlobale,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "StatistiqueGlobale",
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
  },

  MainMenu: {
    screen: MainMenu,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "MainMenu",
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
```

and i use this function in the main menu to navigate to any page by passing it's name in the parameters

```
  navig = (page) => {

    this.props.navigation.navigate(page);

  };
```

and then these two errors appears everytime i try to navigate :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xtre.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGfQU.png)

Answer (score -1):

I will not say I was facing the same problem. The thing is I had to install another package which is "react-native-svg" via npm not yarn. And it started working. And I am using react-native-cli not expo-cli.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.